# $http GET request only working when I refresh the page

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have an AngularJS app that is connected to MongoDB. I have articles that I am pulling from the database that is then ng-repeated onto an article page. I have a button with Read More... that takes the user to the specific article. When the single article view becomes active I make a get request to the database to get the article._id. The get request is only working on page reload and not when I activate the view. See code below...

AngularJS Controller

```
app.controller('ArticleViewController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$routeParams', '$window', function($scope, $location, $http, $routeParams, $window){
// $window.location.reload();

let id = $routeParams.id;

console.log(id);

$http({
    cache: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/:id'
    params: { id }
}).then(function successCallback(res) {
    $scope.article = res.data;
}).catch(function errorCallback(err) {
    if (err) {
        alert('THERE WAS AN ERROR WITH THE DATABASE');
    }
});

}]);
```

The interesting thing is that I am getting the routeParams.id so part of the controller is working. Also, when I uncomment the $window.location.reload the article loads but it just loads the JSON object into the browser window. Thank you in advance for any help.

Routing with Express and Mongoose Schema

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next){
Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, article){
        if(err) {
        return err;
     } else {
        console.log(article);
        res.json(article);
   } 
});
});
```

Mongoose Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var articleSchema = new Schema({
image: String,
title: String,
about: String,
article: String,
id: String

});

var Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

module.exports = Article
```

Nodejs w/Express

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
// const api = require('api');
// const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const logger = require('morgan');

const env = require('./env');
const routeMw = require('./public/middleware/routing.mw');

let article = require('./public/routes/article')
let guide = require('./public/routes/guide')

const app = express();
const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, "./public");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/article', article);
app.use('/guide', guide)
app.use('/article/:id', article);
```

Comment: What happens if you visit the url with the id in your browser? for example localhost/123 where 123 is the id. Is it showing something?

Comment: you can't have a dynamic URL in $http request, change it from `url: '/:id'` to `url: '/'+id,`. Also remove `cache: true`, it [uses the previously stored response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)

Answer (score 0):

**You have syntex error problm in http request.**
**You have need to change in parms paramiter i think show.**

```
app.controller('ArticleViewController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$routeParams', '$window', function($scope, $location, $http, $routeParams, $window){
// $window.location.reload();

let id = $routeParams.id;

console.log(id);

$http({
    cache: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/:id'
    params:{"id": id}
}).then(function successCallback(res) {
    $scope.article = res.data;
}).catch(function errorCallback(err) {
    if (err) {
        alert('THERE WAS AN ERROR WITH THE DATABASE');
    }
});

}]);
```

Comment: Yes, that was a problem but still did not solve the get request issue. Thank you Devendra

Comment: can you send your full url ? now problms in your url.

Comment: you have also check response in console.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the correct article in the console. I just happens when I refresh instead when the view is active.

Comment: the full url is /article/:id using mongoose.

Comment: @JamesBrett You shouldn't try to add a contribution to Devendra's Answer. If this was additional information important to your quesiton, use the EDIT link below *your question* - don't change the Answer. If you think that the Answer is correct with the additional information, put it in your own answer. Or at least get permission from Devendra to change his answer, or let him change his answer.

Comment: woops didn't realize I did that my bad

Comment: You need to put this http request inside the function and then call this function on route change.